# React warnings point out to the bundle, not the actual file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app, react-scripts

I use `react-script start`, and in chrome console I see warnings point not to the jsx file but bundle.js. Debugging works proper however using the original files, so it looks that sourcemap works (or not?). Is it possible to see points to the original files.
Example of the warning:

```
Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
at input
at li
at ul
at TodosList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:430:5)
at section
at Main (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:340:5)
at section
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35:76)
```